# Rails .save() Doesn't Store Id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I'm writing a RESTful API in Rails and when I create a Label object and use the `.save()` method, the label is properly saved to the database but calling `@label.id` returns null.

The `puts` statement verifies that everything is correct except the id field. I have also verified that the database has the proper ids.

Also of note: this is inside of a nested resource URL: `POST /members/:member_id/labels/`.

Has anyone experienced this before?

```
def create
  if params[:member_id] and params[:title]

    # Periods in a username will have been translated to underscores
    member_id = params[:member_id].gsub('_', '.')
    title = params[:title]

    # @member = Member.find(member_id) # No longer in use
    @label = Label.new(:username => member_id, :title => title)

    if @label.save

      puts " *** label: #{@label.inspect}"
      @label.reload

      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => @label, :status => :created and return }
      end
    else
      respond_with :status => 406, :errors => @label.errors and return
    end

  end

  respond_with :status => 406, :errors => [ :message => "member_id and title parameters must be provided" ] and return
end
```

Unfortunately, I cannot provide a migration file as asked since I am connecting to an existing PostgreSQL database originally viewed through PHP. However, below is the `create table` statement along with what a `select *` looks like.

```
DROP TABLE student_labels;
CREATE TABLE student_labels (
  id serial not null,
  username text not null,
  title text not null,
  created_at timestamp not null default now(),
  updated_at timestamp not null default now(),
  deleted_at timestamp
);
```

```
development=> select * from student_labels;
 id | username |    title     |         created_at         |         updated_at         | deleted_at
----+----------+--------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------
  7 | F0003    | Boom         | 2011-03-10 05:49:06.01771  | 2011-03-10 05:49:06.01771  |
  8 | F0003    | Boom         | 2011-03-10 05:49:28.659    | 2011-03-10 05:49:28.659    |
  9 | F0003    | Boom         | 2011-03-10 05:52:03.343815 | 2011-03-10 05:52:03.343815 |
 10 | F0003    | Boom         | 2011-03-10 05:53:07.803489 | 2011-03-10 05:53:07.803489 |
```

Comment: In your puts did you mean to use `"label: #{@label.inspect}"`?  Because from what I see the non-instance variable `label` doesn't exist?

Comment: I think @label.reload is not required. Check your database entry. And yes your puts statement has 'label' which doesn't exists.

Comment: Can you show us migration for labels table?

Comment: @nzifnab - Indeed, I did mean `@label.inspect`, updated code to reflect this.

@ashnish - `@label.reload` should not be required as far as I can tell, someone just suggested I try it.

@Chirantan - Added SQL info, originally done in PHP, so no migration file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `id` column isn't a primary key so the database doesn't know what to give rails when it asks for the `id` of the last inserted row.

Comment: +1 - Thanks so much for the help! I can't believe I missed that...although, it was at 1:00 in the morning when I was working on it :-)